# Convert a distribution of a varialbe to another one

Tags: distributions, binning

Assume an experiment where the observable is `t` and is related to another variable `E` with the following formula: $$E(t)=A/(t-t_0)^2$$ where $A$ and $t_0$ are constants.

In the experiment we measure different values of $t$ and we create a distribution $R(t)$, with a particular binning, not necessarily linear (could be logarithmic).

How can I convert $R(t)$ to $R(E)$  i.e. convert the distribution of $t$ to a distribution of $E$?